# Plot Red Channel from 3D Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, python-imaging-library

Suppose that we have an RGB image that we have converted it to a Numpy array with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('Peppers.tif')
arr = np.array(img) # 256x256x3 array
```

If we are interested in visualizing only the red channel, i.e. `arr[:,:,0]`, how can we plot this 2D Numpy array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use matplotlib's imshow():

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
imgplot = plt.imshow(arr[:, :, 0])
```

see more examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html), for interpolation, colorbars, etc.

For example to change the colormap, you can do `imgplot.set_cmap('hot')`.
Setting interpolation to `'nearest'` is useful too, if you don't really want interpolation: see the differences

```
t = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]])
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(t)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(t, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

results in 
[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is anyway to fix the colormap for different channels like red, gree, blue?

Comment: Also, you can use `img = plt.imread('Peppers.tif')` to read the image directly as a numpy array.